# Get the route value from url in webapi attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I have a webAPI controller which is like

```
Public class TestController:APIController
{ 


   [Route(“Api/Test/{testId}/SubTest”)] 
     Public  void Post(int subTestid)
     {
     }

}
```

Our requirement is to get the value of testId from the url inside the post method.
Could anyone suggest the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this link: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

> The string "customers/{customerId}/orders" is the URI template for the
>   route. Web API tries to match the request URI to the template. In this
>   example, "customers" and "orders" are literal segments, and
>   "{customerId}" is a variable parameter.

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    [Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Order> FindOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
}
```

It seems that you need to change subTestid to testId so it will be a match.

Comment: My url will be like Customers/300/orders/1

Comment: If u need the orders for customer number 300 it will look like that: Customers/300/orders

Comment: I want to get the order with id 1 for the customer with id 300.

Comment: I found an answer in the article link you have given above. Thanks.              [Route("customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}")]
public Order GetOrderByCustomer(int customerId, int orderId) { ... }